# The text is not replaced correctly in the body HTML

Tags: javascript, html, diacritics

I have this in my HTML Body:

```
<p>loaded y&EACUTE;t.</p>
```

With JavaScript I have this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
document.body.innerHTML =  document.body.innerHTML.replace('ACUTE', 'acute');});
```

the result shown in the browser:

```
loaded y&Eacute;t
```

but the expected result:

```
loaded yÉt
```

Any idea how to properly replace the code and display accents with javascript?

Comment: Just match on EACUTE and put '&#201;' Take a look at this site for reference http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `&amp;EACUTE;` with  `&#201;`

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace('&amp;EACUTE;', '&#201;');
    alert(document.body.innerHTML.replace('&amp;EACUTE;', '&#201;'));
});
```

Comment: Thats ok, just a quick update this site may help with other characters http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm